# How to force reset accessibility identifiers in tableview after animation?

Tags: swift, tableview, accessibility, xcuitest

I have a tableview that has cells that expand when selected. This is done by changing the cell height in a performBatchUpdates block within didSelectRowAt. When a cell is expanded, its child views,  a field and a button, are revealed. The problem is the accessibility identifiers for these child elements are not being picked up by the accessibility engine. Which apart from making the app less accessible, also means my XCUITests that try to find these elements using their identifiers fail.

Currently the only way I've found to make the accessibility identifiers visible to the accessibility engine is to call tableView.reloadData() after the animation is complete. However this is not ideal as it makes the otherwise smooth animation glitchy. I have tried also using UIAccessibility.post(.layoutChanged, nextElement) but this hasn't helped. I have tried turning on and off isAccessibilityElement when children are/are not visible.

In the View Debugger, the accessibility Identifiers are present for the child elements, and they are reported as being accessibility elements. Yet the accessibility engine is still not able to pick them up. So my question is how can I make these elements visible to accessibility engine after animating the cells?

simplified code:

```swift
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let item = items[indexPath.row]
            tableView.performBatchUpdates( { 
items.map { $0.setCVVVNotVisible() }       
 item.setCVVVisible()
 }, completion: nil ) 
        }
    }
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return items[indexPath.row].isVisible ? 215 : 75
}
```

And in the TableViewCell

```swift
outputs
            .displayCVV
            .bind { isVisible in
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

                    self.cvvInputField.accessibilityIdentifier = isVisible ?
                        "payment.card.cvv.field.\(self.index)" : nil
                    self.payButton.accessibilityIdentifier = isVisible ?  "payment.card.pay.button.\(self.index)" : nil
                    self.cvvInputField.isAccessibilityElement = isVisible
                    self.payButton.isAccessibilityElement = isVisible
                    UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: isVisible ? self.cvvInputField : self)

                }
            }
```

Would expect accessibility engine and XCUITest to be able to find the payButton and cvvInput field as view debugger is reporting these as having their identifiers correctly set. However the accessibility engine (using both accessibility inspector and in XCUITests) is unable to find these elements, unless an extra called to tableview.reloadData() is made after the animation.

Comment: Did you try to update your accessibilyIdentifier in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method ?

Comment: Yes have set accessibility identifiers there